# What's a robust way to insert another extension into a filename?

Tags: string-manipulation, files-and-directories

I'd like to add an extension to a filename before the file extension, otherwise leaving the given filename the same. In particular, absolute filenames should stay absolute, and relative filenames should stay relative. Examples: suppose the piece I want to insert is `".123"`, then

- `/home/me/dir/foo.txt` becomes `/home/me/dir/foo.123.txt`.
- `xyz.csv` becomes `xyz.123.csv`
- `foobar` becomes `foobar.123` (just append in case of no extension)

I don't expect to be dealing with filenames that already have multiple extensions, but just in case, the desired behavior is

- `nomnom.tar.gz` becomes `nomnom.123.tar.gz`

I can ensure that the filename does not end with a slash.

The obvious way to do this is by concatenating the directory name, the file base name, the new piece, and the extension:

```
insertPiece[fn_, piece_] := FileNameJoin[{
      DirectoryName[fn],
      StringJoin[{FileBaseName[fn], piece, ".", FileExtension[fn]}]
}]
```

but is there some corner case I missed in which this wouldn't work? Is there a more efficient or more elegant way to do it?

Comment: `insertPiece[]` won't work nicely on tarballs like `stuff.tar.gz`.

Comment: Ah, good point. Multi-extension files won't (or shouldn't) come up in the particular application I'm using this for, but I think I'll modify it to take that into account just in case.

Comment: The whole filename extension thing is a bit ill-defined.  In the example `nomnom.123.tar.gz` above, I would consider `nomnom.123` to be the base filename and `tar.gz` to be the extension (I know I have files on my computer that I would want the code to view like this). Without having a list of "valid" file extensions, this would be hard to program in general.

Comment: Here's the definition I'm using: split the last component of the filename on the character `"."`. The first element of the resulting list is the base filename, and all the rest of the elements in the list are extensions.

Comment: @David: That's what [my code](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/525/34) does. I was just pointing out that it's not what might always be wanted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's my non-regex solution (but it does use a "[String Pattern](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/StringPatterns.html)", which is equivalent to regex). I think it is robust.

```
insertExtension[fn_String, piece_String] := 
 Module[{split = FileNameSplit[fn], temp},
  temp = Insert[StringSplit[Last[split], "."], piece, 2];
  temp = StringJoin[Riffle[temp, "."]];
  FileNameJoin[Append[Most[split], temp]]]
```

Test:

```
In[]:= insertExtension["/home/me.em/dir.ab/nomnom.tar.gz", "123"]

Out[]= "/home/me.em/dir.ab/nomnom.123.tar.gz"
```

Comment: I think this one looks a little cleaner, so I'm accepting your answer. Though is there any reason to use `Module` instead of `Block`?

Comment: @David: My rule of thumb is to use `Block` if I need to temporarily redefining (or undefine) and existing symbol inside the block. And `Module` for standard lexical scoping. `Block` can be slightly faster and since the above code is quite self contained (no calls to functions that might depend on ``Global`split`` or ``Global`temp``) it should be safe to use `Block`.

Comment: Standard references: [Blocks Compared with Modules](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/BlocksComparedWithModules.html), [Mathematica Module versus With or Block - Guideline, rule of thumb for usage?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6661939/421225) and [local variables and the code modularization](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node48.html)

Comment: Also [Condition, Block, Module - which way is the most memory and computationally efficient?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7596460/421225) and very recently on Mma.SE [What are the use cases for different scoping constructs?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/559/34)

Answer (score 10):

String manipulation like this is probably done best using regular expressions. If you're not familiar with these, you may want to have a look at the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) or the [Mathematica tutorial on them](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/RegularExpressions.html) first.

The code given below defines a pattern `regex` that matches an extension of the type `.abcDeF...` at the end of a string (that's accomplished by the `$` sign). If that pattern does not match, then the extension is simply added; if the pattern matches, the extension is put in between the rest of the string and the match. Here's the code for that:

```
appendExtension[filename_, extension_] := Block[{regex},
    regex = RegularExpression["\\.[a-z]+$"];
    If[Length@StringCases[filename, regex] == 0,
        filename <> "." <> extension,
        StringReplace[filename, regex -> ("." <> extension <> "$0")]
    ]
];
appendExtension["/home/me/dir/foo.txt", "123"]
appendExtension["xyz.csv", "123"]
appendExtension["foobar", "123"]
```

*Output:*

```
"/home/me/dir/foo.123.txt"
"xyz.123.csv"
"foobar.123"
```

A few remarks:

- I'm not sure how you want filenames like `foo.bar.baz` to be handled. The code above replaces this by `foo.bar.123.baz`, i.e. takes only the last extension into account. If you want the new one inserted as the leftmost one, change the regular expression to `(\\.[a-z]+)+$`, and the replacement will yield `foo.123.bar.baz`.
- The regex doesn't include upper case extensions or digits. To add these, change `[a-z]` inside the regex to `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

Comment: This should work nicely, especially because I'm very comfortable with regular expressions but I always forget that Mathematica can use them too :-) FWIW in a case with multiple extensions, the new one should be the first extension of the resulting filename, though as I mentioned in a comment on the question I don't expect that case to come up. But I'll edit my question accordingly.