# What are the use cases for different scoping constructs?

Tags: functions, scoping, variable-definitions, function-comparison

Mathematica includes three functions that I know of which can be used to effectively (if not actually) define a variable and give it a value within a local scope: `Module`, `Block`, and `With`. What are the differences between these functions (and any other scoping constructs that may exist which I don't know about), and how do I decide which one is appropriate to use in any given instance?

The documentation does describe what the different constructs do to some extent, but I feel like it's insufficiently clear on how exactly they differ from each other. Having some short examples that demonstrate the differences would be great.

Comment: I find the documentation for `Module`, `Block` and `With` to be quite confusing, but the tutorials [How Modules Work](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/HowModulesWork.html), [Blocks and Local Values](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/BlocksAndLocalValues.html) and [Local Constants](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LocalConstants.html) are a much nicer introduction and much more straightforward than the documentation.

Comment: Older question on SO: [Mathematica Module versus With or Block - Guideline, rule of thumb for usage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661393/mathematica-module-versus-with-or-block-guideline-rule-of-thumb-for-usage)

Comment: Related: "[Plot using With versus Plot using Block](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6236458/590388)."

Comment: Cross-posted on WC: "[Scoping constructs in Wolfram Language](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1017668)."

Answer (score 257, accepted):

You will find a lot of information in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661393/mathematica-module-versus-with-or-block-guideline-rule-of-thumb-for-usage) answer. I will add a few personal notes.

### Module

Use `Module` when you want to localize variables inside your function's body, and those variables will potentially acquire and/or change their values during the computation.

#### Basic use

For example:

```
f[x_]:=Module[{y=x^2},y=y+x;{x,y}]
```

Here, a local mutable variable (symbol) `y` is local to the `Module`, and is, indeed, a symbol with a unique name. This is the closest you have in Mathematica to, say, local variables in C.

#### Advanced uses

`Module` also has advanced uses. One of them is to create closures - functions with a persistent state. My third post in [this](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/5eff6213a0ab5f51) thread illustrates many cases of that and has further references. One example I will steal from there:  the following function will produce the next Fibonacci number on demand, and yet it will be as fast as the iterative loop implementation for generation of consecutive Fibonacci numbers (since Module is invoked only once, when the function is defined):

```
Module[{prev, prevprev, this}, 
   reset[] := (prev = 1; prevprev = 1); 
   reset[]; 
   nextFib[] := (this = prev + prevprev; prevprev = prev; prev = this)
];

 
reset[]; 
Table[nextFib[], {1000}]; // Timing 

(* 
  ---> {0.01, Null} 
*)
```

One problem with persistence created with `Module`-variables is that one should not generally serialize such state (definitions), for example by saving the state via `Save` or `DumpSave`. This is because, the uniqueness of names for `Module`-generated symbols is guaranteed only within a single Mathematica session.

`Module` also allows one to create *local functions*, which `With` does not (except pure functions). This is a very powerful capability. It is particularly useful for writing recursive functions, but not only. In the link mentioned above, there were examples of this. One problem with local functions created by `Module` is that these symbols won't be automatically garbage-collected when `Module` finishes (if they have `DownValues`, `SubValues` or `UpValues`. `OwnValues` are fine), and so may lead to memory leaks. To avoid that, one can `Clear` these symbols inside `Module` before returning the result.

### With

Use `With` to define local constants, which can not be changed inside the body of your function.

#### Basic use

For example,

```
f[x_,y_]:=With[{sum = x+y},{sum *x, sum *y}]
```

It is instructive to trace the execution of `f`. You will notice that `sum` gets replaced by its value very early on, before the body starts evaluating. This is quite unlike `Module`, where variable entries get replaced by their values in the process of evaluation, just as it would normally happen were the variables global.

#### Advanced uses

On an advanced level, `With` can be used to inject some evaluated code deep into some expression which is otherwise unevaluated:

```
With[{x=5},Hold[Hold[x^2]]]

(*
    Hold[Hold[5^2]]
*)
```

and is thus an important meta-programming tool. There are lots of uses for this feature, in particular one can use this to inject code into `Compile` at run-time right before compilation. This can extend the capabilities / flexibility of `Compile` quite a bit. One example can be found in my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973424/in-mathematica-how-do-i-compile-the-function-outer-for-an-arbitrary-number-of) question.

The semantics of `With` is similar to that of rule substitutions, but an important difference is that `With` cares about inner scoping constructs (during variable name collisions), while rules don't. Both behaviors can be useful in different situations.

#### Module vs With

Both of these are *lexical* scoping constructs, which means that they bind their variables to lexical their occurrences in the code. Technically, the major difference between them is that  you can not change the values of constants initialized in `With`, in the body of `With`, while you can change values of `Module` variables inside the body. On a deeper level, this is because `With` does not generate any new symbols. It does all the replacements before the body evaluates, and by that time no "constant symbols" are at all present, all of them replaced with their values. `Module`, OTOH, does generate temporary symbols (which are normal symbols with an attribute `Temporary`), which can store a mutable state.

Stylistically, it is better to use `With` if you know that your variables are in fact constants, i.e. they won't change during the code execution. Since `With` does not create extra (mutable) state, the code is cleaner. Also, you have more chances to catch an occasional erroneous attempt in the code to modify such a constant.

Performance-wise, `With` tends to be faster than `Module`, because it does not have to create new variables and then destroy them. This however usually only shows up for very light-weight functions. I would not base my preference of one over another on performance boosts.

### Block

#### Basic use

`Block` localizes the *value* of the variable. In this example, `a` does not refer to `i` *literally* inside `Block`, but still uses the value set by `Block`.

```
a:=i
Block[{i=2},a]
{a,i}
```

`Block` therefore affects the *evaluation stack*, not just the literal occurrences of a symbol inside the code of its body. Its effects are much less local than those of lexical scoping constructs, which makes it much harder to debug programs which use `Block` extensively. It is not much different from using global variables, except that `Block`guarantees that their values will be restored to their previous values once the execution exits `Block` (which is often a big deal). Even so, this non-transparent and non-local manipulation of the variable values is one reason to avoid using `Block` where `With` and / or `Module` can be used. But there are more (see below).

In practice, my advice would be to avoid using `Block` unless you know quite well why you need it. It is more error-prone to use it for variable localization than `With` or `Module`, because it does not prevent variable name collisions, and those will be quite hard to debug. One of the reasons people suggest to use `Block` is that they claim it is faster. While it is true, my opinion is that the speed advantage is minimal while the risk is high. I elaborated on this point [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596460/condition-block-module-which-way-is-the-most-memory-and-computationally-effi/7597238#7597238), where at the bottom there is also an idiom which allows one to have the best of both worlds. In addition to these reasons, as noted by @Albert Retey, using `Block` with the `Dynamic` - related functionality may lead to nasty surprises, and errors resulting from that may also be quite non-local and hard to find.

One valid use of `Block` is to temporarily redefine some global system settings / variables. One of the most common such use cases is when we want to temporarily change the value of `$RecursionLimit` or `$IterationLimit` variables. Note however that while using `Block[{$IterationLimit = Infinity}, ...]` is generally okay, using  `Block[{$RecursionLimit = Infinity}, ...]` is not, since the stack space is limited and if it gets exhausted, the kernel will crash. A detailed discussion of this topic and how to make functions tail-recursive in Mathematica, can be found e.g. in my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481301/tail-call-optimization-in-mathematica).

It is quite interesting that the same ability of `Block` can be used to significantly extend the control the user has over namespaces/symbol encapsulation. For example, if you want to load a package, but not add its context to the `$ContextPath` (may be, to avoid shadowing problems), all you have to do is

```
Block[{$ContextPath}, Needs[Your-package]]
```

As another example, some package you want to load modifies some other function (say, `` System`SomeFunction ``), and you want to prevent that without changing the code of the package. Then, you use something like

```
Block[{SomeFunction}, Needs[That-package]]
```

which ensures that all those modifications did not affect actual definitions for `SomeFunction`  - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702590/fixing-combinatorica-redefinition-of-element/4720679#4720679) for an example of this.

#### Advanced uses

`Block` is a very powerful metaprogramming device, because you can make every symbol (including system functions) temporarily "forget" what it is (its definitions and other global properties), and this may allow one to change the order of evaluation of an expression involving that symbol(s) in non-trivial ways, which may be hard to achieve by other means of evaluation control (this won't work on `Locked` symbols). There are many examples of this at work, one which comes to mind now is the `LetL` macro from my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866016/question-on-condition) question.

Another more advanced use of `Block` is to ensure that all used variables would be restored to their initial values, even in the case of Abort or exception happening somewhere inside the body of `Block`. In other words, it can be used to ensure that the system will not find itself in an illegal state in the case of sudden failure. If you wrap your critical (global) variables in `Block`, it will guarantee you this.

A related use of `Block` is when we want to be sure that some symbols will be cleared at the end. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342748/dynamic-programming-in-mathematica-how-to-automatically-localize-and-or-clear/) and answers there represent good examples of using `Block` for this purpose.

#### Variable name conflicts

In nested scoping constructs, it may happen that they define variables with the same names. Such conflicts are typically resolved in favor of the inner scoping construct. The documentation contains more details.

#### Block vs Module/With

So, `Block` implements dynamic scoping, meaning that it binds variables in time rather than in space. One can say that a variable localized by `Block` will have its value during the time this `Block` executes (unless further redefined inside of it, of course). I tried to outline the differences between `Block` and `With`/`Module` (dynamic vs lexical scoping) in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236458/plot-using-with-versus-plot-using-block-mathematica/6236808#6236808)  answer.

#### Some conclusions

- For most common purposes of variable localization, use `Module`
- For local constants, use `With`
- Do not ordinarily use `Block` for introducing local variables
- All of the scoping constructs under discussion have advanced uses. For `Module` this is mostly creating and encapsulating non-trivial state (persistent or not). For `With`, this is mostly injecting inside unevaluated expressions. For `Block`, there are several advanced uses, but all of them are, well, advanced. I'd be worried if I found myself using `Block` a lot, but there are cases when it is indispensable.

Comment: very clear. well-deserved +1

Comment: @acl Thanks! I knew there will be many answers, but just could not resist:). I actually consider two of my strongest mma areas to be scoping and performance-tuning, so whenever there is a discussion on those, I go out of control, as you correctly noted some few days ago :)

Comment: You mentioned that Module-locale symbols with DownValues don't get garbage collected, which sounded worrying, so I tried `Module[{a},
 a[1] = 1;
 ]` in a fresh kernel.  In this case `a` (or rather its renamed version) does get garbage collected.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Szabolcs You need to refer to such function by some global object first, which you can later `Remove` - it is in such cases that we get into trouble. For example: `ClearAll[f];Module[{a}, a[1] = 1; f[x_] := a[x]];Remove[f]`. Even though we later removed `f`, the local `a` was not collected. Clearing `$HistoryLenth` does not seem to help. I was actually bitten by this quite seriously a few times, when I worked in an OO fashion and abandoned lots of such objects. So, I ended up with modified `Module` where I could clean up manually later.

Comment: I got it now.  I can also reproduce by playing with `Temporary`.  It is an interesting (non-obvious) observation you make that `Clear[a]` will allow `a` to get garbage collected.  I'll add that `ClearAll` will *not* (because it removes the `Temporary` attribute).  Can you edit your post and change `ClearAll` to `Clear`?

Comment: @Szabolcs To put it differently: collection is only attempted just before we leave `Module`. Because the local function was still referenced by a global symbol at that point, it could not be collected then. And it turns out that in such cases, it gets the "rights" of a global object - it becomes a global object. Even though it still has a `Temporary` attribute, it will *never* be automatically collected, regardless of what happens to the symbols which were referencing it.

Comment: To make it more clear, `Module[{a},
 ClearAll[a]
 ]` will prevent the renamed version of `a` from being removed.  Try it in a fresh kernel then do ``?Global`*``

Comment: @Szabolcs Now you've made a good observation, thanks! I actually recall that I got that at some point when was experimenting with it (when it mattered), but forgot about `Clear / ClearAll` subtlety since then (it has been 3 years or something). This is because I actually started doing things differently, frequently even using `Remove` instead. I will surely edit.

Comment: A small correction to this comment: "Even though it still has a Temporary attribute, it will *never* be automatically collected, regardless of what happens to the symbols which were referencing it."  It's probably better not to stress *never*.  In a simple test, it does get garbage collected if it is not referenced any more *and* its downvalues are removed.  I did `$HistoryLength = 0;  Module[{a}, a[]=1; f=a; name = SymbolName[a]]; Clear[f]; With[{s = name}, Clear[s]]`  The renamed `a` gets garbage collected only at the very last step.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, of course, I said *never* meaning that it preserves its content. I meant that it does not depend now on which symbols were originally referencing it. I mentioned the presence of one of the `...Values` (except `OwnValues`) as a preresuisite for this behavior.

Comment: Let's get some rest, it's way too late :-)  (2:30 here)

Comment: @Szabolcs I wanted to suggest the same :) 4:30 here, and I must bring my kid to the kindergarden at 9... Good night!

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, well sumarized. Two additions: Block[{$RecusionLeverl=}] type of thinks and Performance for Block is very good since no new symbols need to be created.

Comment: @ruebenko Thanks. I mentioned that `Block` is faster, but I also mentioned that, except possibly in packages, this speed boost comes at a risk of name collisions, so I personally tend to avoid it for such purposes. I actually linked to the SO question where the speed comparison is elaborated. As to your first point - perhaps I should have mentioned this use case, but I noticed after posting that it was mentioned in other answers. Do you think it would still be better to include it here? Also, there is a bunch of other more subtle things that I left out here.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, I think is would be useful to include, since this comes up again and again, it would be good to have a reference that is complete, kind of a wiki. If you don't mind the work.

Comment: @ruebenko I don't mind the work :) Will include, and also think of a few other important cases and / or subtleties.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, I don't know, I somehow did have that impression ;-)

Comment: When discussing _lexical scoping_ you make this statement: "they bind their variables to lexical their occurrences in the code" which doesn't make sense to me. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I think this if fairly complete, I just would like to mention another example why Block is dangerous: It can incidentally trigger Dynamic evaluations -- and in extreme cases hang or crash the FrontEnd. Evaluate this to see why: `Dynamic[x]` and then in another cell this: `Block[{x},x=1;Pause[1]]`

Comment: @Albert Thanks, your opinion is valuable to me. B.t.w., I did evaluate your example, but nothing bad happened (Win7, 64 bit, M8.0.0). I probably missed something. What was supposed to happen?

Comment: @rcollyer Sorry, I somehow missed your comment. I think I was too tired yesterday. I meant something like "bind the variables in all places where they are literally present in the body, but not say in the code called when body evaluates".

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: In that simple case nothing bad happens, it just shows that while you might think that the localized x will be harmless, it will actually trigger the dynamic. Nothing too surprising when seen in this simple case, but very bad if you imagine a more complex setup. Think of a couple of such Dynamics and e.g. a Map[f,Range[10000]] where f uses such a block and the Dynamics that seems unrelated go havoc. I have crashed the FrontEnd that way and it was very hard to find that error. Of course I should have used other means to localize -- but that's what the comment was all about :-)

Comment: Another comment on the Dynamic example, maybe a little off topic: Would anyone except for me condider it as a bug that the `Dynamic[x]` will keep showing 1 even after `Block[{x},x=1;Pause[1]]` has finished and a shift-return-evaluation will show that x has no value defined anymore? Using a `Clear[x]` will make it update...

Comment: @Albert I see now. Edited, please see if it's ok. Quite frankly, while `Dynamic` is a cool concept and I've used it a lot, I think it goes a bit against the design ideology behind Mathematica, part of which is to expose to the user enough internals to make things intuitive and understandable at the core. To put it differently, while I'd use it for prototyping, I'd probably resort to other means (Java Swing, or web interface and Javascript) if I had to make UI-s for production to be used by others - just because I can not be sure how it will behave in this or that case. May be it's just me.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: I agree that the Dynamic functionality has its drawbacks and limits. But one can do more than I first thought when being careful. We use it to create even relatively complex guis for customers that run them in PlayerPro. Unfortunately you can't use any of the alternatives when it's supposed to run with PlayerPro. As for your edit, it expresses exactly what I meant -- no complaints (and it even mentions me :-)

Comment: When I first learned of `With`, I had original thought it wouldn't create new symbols (which is also what you say).  But running `With[{i = 2},
 f[x_] := i*x]` followed by ``Names["Global`*"]`` in a fresh kernel yields `{"f", "i", "x", "x$"}`, indicating that on the contrary the symbol `i` *is* created (version 10.2). Any idea of what's going on?

Comment: @QuantumDot The symbol `i` is created not by `With`, but by the FrontEnd parser, because the code is parsed long before `With` has any chance to fire, and symbols are created during parsing (symbols are also created by `Module` and `Unique`, of course, but not by `With` or `Block`). This is another reason why it is a good idea to place all implementation in ``"`Private`"`` sub-context of the package - since then all such symbols are created in the private section of the package.

Comment: "One problem with local functions created by `Module` is that these symbols won't be automatically garbage-collected when `Module` finishes (if they have `DownValues`...)" Maybe this is changed in recent versions of *Mathematica*?

Comment: @unlikely I don't think so. Check the nested `Module` example from [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6179/81), it illustrates exactly this issue, and the problem still exists. It may well be that this issue is unsolvable within the currently existing model of lexical scoping in Mathematica - although this I can't tell for sure.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin This apply to "complex" situation like the example? In a simple case like `Module[{f}, f[x_] := x^2]` without cross-references, is the `f` garbage collected despite having `DownValues`? Or does I need to `Clear[f]` or do something else before leaving `Module` to avoid leaks?

Comment: @unlikely In the simple case you considered, garbage collection works all right. The problem happens only when the local symbol (`f` in your case) with `DownValues` (or `SubValues`, `UpValues`)  is referenced by something more global, at the time when such definition is made. In the example from that link, it was referenced by a variable local by the enclosing scope. Note that even though that variable was later garbage-collected, this didn't help the inner variable.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Thanks, I can now clean some of my code removing unecessary `Clear`... :)

Comment: @unlikely Was glad to help.

Comment: Hello again; I've been studying your "advanced" use of *Module* to create closures; but I'm not fully understanding it.  I thought the key point/advantage here is that the variables `prev`, `prevprev`, `this` are totally inaccessible except by using `reset[]` or `nextFib[]`.  However, this is not completely true since they still appear in the ``Global` `` context as `prev$317`, `prevprev$317`, *etc* (the 317=`$ModuleNumber`), and I can even corrupt the functions by modifying *e.g.* `prev$317 = 0.133`.  Could you clarify the advantage of this use case over just having the code outside `Module`?

Comment: @QuantumDot You can't make variables fully inaccessible in Mathematica, for reasons I have outlined [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119410/81). So, yes, this is a fundamental limitation. However, normally one would not come up with such  variables as what `Module` is producing. Closures are most useful because they can access the variables from surrounding environment. The fact that in Mathematica, the user can (with some effort) also access those variables, does not make closures less useful - it makes the lexical scoping less robust, but there isn't much one can do about this.

Comment: Hey @LeonidShifrin, long time no see (I hope you are doing well). I would like to respond to your statement "In practice, my advice would be to avoid using Block unless [...]". I felt that it needed to be said that `Table` and `Do` etc also work like `Block` (as mentioned by Szabolcs), so that it is in that sense impossible to avoid such issues with the advice to avoid `Block`. I feel that the advice may lead to a false sense of security, or an unwillingness to understand something that really needs to be understood anyway, even if the advice does help avoid some tricky situations.

Comment: Well, that is just my 5 cents. I am not regularly using MMASE or mathematica anymore, so please forgive me if I am not available to continue the discussion timely/in-depth. Your advice always stuck with me, I also hope you forgive me if this is not the first time I brought this up and I simply don't remember your reply. Have a nice day :¬)

Comment: Hey @JacobAkkerboom, nice to hear from you! I hope you are doing well too. I agree that `Do` and `Table` scope dynamically, so certainly those who use them have to know at least on a basic level, what dynamic scoping is. But I also think that one needs to know more to effectively use (and not misuse!) `Block`, than to use those two constructs, since `Block` is more general. If you strongly feel that your remark on `Do` and `Table` should be added to my reply, feel free to edit it in, or I can do that as well.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Re:  "I am not regularly using MMASE or mathematica anymore" - I am a lot less frequent visitor of MMASE these days too, although my work is still directly related to Mathematica / WL. I wonder whether you have found a replacement which better fits your domain / work, or you switched the fields and don't anymore deal with types of problems, which are easily solved with tools like Mathematica. In any case, this site and community will miss you and your contributions - unless of course you decide to occasionally pop up here and answer a question or two :)

Comment: I do not strongly feel that my remarks should be added to your answer, these comments that address my concerns make my concerns sufficiently visible.

Comment: I gradually stopped using Mathematica when I got a new job, lacking a license played a role here. In my new job I mainly use [Google Apps Script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Apps_Script). Thank you for your swift and thoughtful reply, the community and your contributions are truly extraordinary :¬)

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Thanks for the kind words :) But your contributions to this site also made it a lot better. B.t.w, I was recently refreshing on LibraryLink and found your posts quite valuable for that. I hope you are enjoying your new job and doing great! Its good to occasionally cross paths, M SE is also useful for that :)

Answer (score 106):

The differences between `Module`, `Block` and `With` are nicely summarized by the results of the following expressions:

```
x = "global"; f[] := x

Module[{x = "local"}, {x, f[], Hold[x]}]
 Block[{x = "local"}, {x, f[], Hold[x]}]
  With[{x = "local"}, {x, f[], Hold[x]}]
```

which returns:

```
{"local", "global", Hold[x$123]}        (* Module *)
{"local", "local",  Hold[x]}            (* Block *)
{"local", "global", Hold["local"]}      (* With *)
```

**Executive Summary**

`Module`: the work-horse of scoping constructs -- use it unless you have special needs

`Block`: use it when you need to temporarily change the definition of an existing symbol

`With`: use it when you need to insert values into held expressions

More details follow...

**Module**

`Module` evaluates its second argument after replacing all of the "local symbols" (`x` in this case) with freshly generated unique temporary symbols.  Thus,

```
Module[{x = "local"}, {x, f[], Hold[x]}]
```

is roughly equivalent to:

```
x$123 = "local"; {x$123, f[], Hold[x$123]}
```

yielding the result:

```
{"local", "global", Hold[x$123]}
```

**Block**

`Block` does not generate "local" symbols.  Instead, temporarily it clears all of the definitions and attributes associated with the supplied symbols, evaluates the second argument, and then restores the cleared definitions.  Thus:

```
Block[{x = "local"}, {x, f[], Hold[x]}]
```

is roughly equivalent to:

```
ClearAll[x]; x = "local"; {x, f[], Hold[x]} /. r_ :> (x = "global"; r)
```

with the result:

```
{"local", "local",  Hold[x]}
```

In practice, the clearing and restoration of the symbol `x` is done more efficiently by the Mathematica kernel.  Take careful note that `f[]` evaluates to `"local"`.  The *global* definition of `x` is changed for the duration of the evaluation of the `Block` expression.  This behaviour can be very surprising, so be sure that this is your intent before using `Block`.

**With**

`With` replaces all occurrences of the listed symbols in the second argument with the corresponding values, and then evaluates the result.  Thus:

```
With[{x = "local"}, {x, f[], Hold[x]}]
```

is equivalent to:

```
{"local", f[], Hold["local"]}
```

with the result:

```
{"local", "global", Hold["local"]}
```

Note especially that `With` differs from the other two constructs in that it can change the contents of held expressions.

**Undocumented Goodies**

`` Internal`InheritedBlock `` acts like `Block`, except that it does not clear the existing definition first.  This is extremely useful if you want to temporarily *augment* the functionality of an existing symbol instead of temporarily replacing it.  I wish this were not "internal".

Due to an implementation coincidence, `Block` (but *not* `With` or `Module`) can be used as a nifty trick to force evaluation on the right hand side of a rule, e.g.

```
Hold[{2, 3}] /. n_Integer :> Block[{}, n*n /; True]
```

`With` can be used in a similar fashion, if more verbose:

```
Hold[{2, 3}] /. n_Integer :> With[{r = n*n}, r /; True]
```

Comment: The last bit, forcing evaluation on the rhs of a rule, is interesting. There isn't much wiggle room, if any. The condition must be inside the block expression, not outside, so the documentation of `Condition` is little help understanding the trick. It must be `RuleDelayed` and not `Rule`, which is a bit easier to understand; you want the trick evaluated after substitution, not before. So it looks like you're getting a `RuleDelayed` that's going to eval a `Condition`; the `Block` incidentally forces one more round of evaluation before the test of the `Condition` -- something along these lines.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin `Trace` will reveal the "implementation coincidence" that these expressions invoke `RuleCondition` in a manner useful to this context.  See also the brief discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7679152/211232).

Comment: Are the brackets on `f` necessary? You could do the same with `y:=x`.

Comment: @episanty The brackets are not strictly necessary but, following common convention, their presence gives the reader a clue that `f` is a potentially non-determinstic computation rather than a simple value.

Comment: It seems that `InheritedBlock` has been made a resource function with some added error messages since 2019 (after this answer was made). The possible issues section might also be interested to look at. The function is [here](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/InheritedBlock/)

Answer (score 42):

I'll cover a few typical uses of `Block`, neither of which is possible using `Module` or `With`.

**Temporarily removing definitions**

When you do

```
Block[ {a = x}, ... ]
```

the original definition of `a` is effectively replaced by whatever new definition is given in the first argument of `Block`, for the duration of the evaluation of `Block` only.  If we give no definition, `Block` temporarily "undefines" whatever was passed to it as first argument.  This works even for built-ins:

```
Block[ {Print}, Print["boo!"]; ]
```

prints nothing.

**Temporarily redefining symbols**

`Block` is also commonly used to temporarily change the value of system variables.  Take for example this simple recursive implementation of a list maximum function:

```
max[{a_}] := a
max[list_List] := 
 With[{m = max@Rest[list]}, If[First[list] > m, First[list], m]]
```

For a long list it fails because the value of `$RecursionLimit` is too low.  But we can increase `$RecursionLimit` only temporarily using `Block`:

```
Block[{$RecursionLimit = 1000}, max[RandomInteger[10000, 300]]]
```

**Implementing functions that localize their arguments**

Functions like `Table`, `Sum`, `Plot`, `FindRoot`, `NIntegrate`, etc. use `Block` to localize their variable.

Here's a possible implementation of a `table` function which works like `Table`:

```
Clear[table]
SetAttributes[table, HoldAll]
table[expr_, {x_, min_, max_, step_}] :=
 Block[{x},
  x = min;
  Reap[While[x <= max,
     Sow[expr];
     x += step
     ]][[2, 1]]
  ]
```

We can use it just like `Table`:

```
table[i, {i, 1, 100, 4}]

(*
 ==> {1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25, 29, 33, 37, 41, 45, 49, 53, 57, \
      61, 65, 69, 73, 77, 81, 85, 89, 93, 97}
*)
```

Using `Block` made sure that this function will work even if `i` has a value globally.

---

**`` Internal`InheritedBlock ``**

Here it's also worth mentioning `` Internal`InheritedBlock ``.  Like with `Block`, any changes made to the local symbols of `InheritedBlock` are lost when it finishes evaluating.  However, unlike `Block`, it keeps the original definition of the localized symbols too.

This is useful for modifying existing (or built-in) functions temporarily.  Here's an example to illustrate:

`Print` does not have the `HoldAll` attribute:

```
Print[1 + 1]

(* ==> 2 *)
```

We can assign `HoldAll` to `Print` temporarily:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[
 {Print},
 SetAttributes[Print, HoldAll];
 Print[1 + 1];
]

(* ==> 1+1 *)
```

As soon as `InheritedBlock` exits, this behaviour is reverted:

```
Print[1 + 1]

(* ==> 2 *)
```

Comment: I too tend to use `Block[]` whenever I have to temporarily redefine system variables like `$IterationLimit`. Nice. :)

Comment: @szabolcs In the last line of the text in the answer above, shouldn't the word _exits_ be used instead of _exists_? (i.e. "As soon as `InheritedBlock` _exits_ ...")

Comment: @zentient Thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 27):

There will no doubt be plenty of answers for this one. However the short answer is:

- Use `With` for local *constants* that you don't have to change subsequently.
- Use  `Module` for local *variables* that are local to that piece of code.
- Use `Block` for local *variables* that are local to that sequence of evaluation.

This [tutorial in the Mathematica documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/BlocksComparedWithModules.html) discusses the difference between `Block` and `Module` in more depth. The essential difference is that `Block` substitutes in the local value of the variable even if the piece of code is calling some other function that was defined outside that `Block` statement, and that uses the same variable name.

In my view, `With` is the least well understood. It is marginally faster for cases where what you have is really a constant, e.g. an intermediate calcuation in a larger function definition. For example, consider a function that returns the contribution of each element to the total, the average value of each element and the sum of squares normalized by the length of the list. The intermediate values of the length and total of the list don't subsequently change, so you can use `With` rather than `Module`.

```
f[x_List]:= With[{n=Length[x],t=Total[x]}, 
   {x/t, t/n, Total[x^2]/n}  ]
```

Other times, it is easier to use `Module` even if the local entity is a constant (i.e. not redefined), because it builds on other local variables. Consider:

```
ff[x_List]:= Module[{n=Length[x],t=Total[x],ssqs}, 
  ssqs = Total[x^2]/n;
   {x/t, t/n, ssqs} ]
```

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, I just noticed the additional answers here. An added point with `With`, you can use `SetDelayed`, which increases its usefulness.

Comment: Yet another scoping construct that I didn't see mentioned is DynamicModule.

Answer (score 23):

I will leave the explanation of the difference between lexical and dynamic to those more qualified than myself (and to the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/BlocksComparedWithModules.html)). One practical difference between `Block` and `Module` is this:

```
Module[{x}, x]
Block[{x}, x]
(*
-> x$1979
   x
*)
```

That is, if you construct something inside a `Block` with a blocked variable and then return it, you may use it. Thus, you may do

```
Block[{Sin = Cos[#/4] &}, Sin[Pi]]
(*
-> 1/Sqrt[2]
*)
```

More usefully, you can do things like `Block[{$RecursionLimit = 1000},...]`, which temporarily changes `$RecursionLimit` (`Module` would not have worked as it renames `$RecursionLimit`).

`With[{x=5},expr]` is slightly different. First, the value of `x` is literally inserted wherever `x` appears in `expr`, even in held expressions:

```
Block[{x = 5}, Hold[x]]
Module[{x = 5}, Hold[x]]
With[{x = 5}, Hold[x]]
(*
Hold[x]
Hold[x$2413]
Hold[5]
*)
```

Consequently, you cannot assign anything to `x` inside expr: try

```
With[{x = 5}, x = Sin[42]] // Trace
Block[{x = 5}, x = Sin[42]; Print[x]] // Trace
Module[{x = 5}, x = Sin[42]; Print[x]] // Trace
(*
{With[{x=5},x=Sin[42]],5=Sin[42] (*lots of errors*)}

Sin[42]

{Block[{x=5},x=Sin[42];Print[x]],{x=5,5},{x=Sin[42];Print[x],{x=Sin[42],Sin[42]},
{{x,Sin[42]},Print[Sin[42]],{MakeBoxes[Sin[42],StandardForm],RowBox[{Sin,
[,42,]}]},Null},Null},Null}


Sin[42]

{Module[{x=5},x=Sin[42];Print[x]],{x$847=5,5},{x$847=Sin[42];Print[x$847],
{x$847=Sin[42],Sin[42]},{{x$847,Sin[42]},Print[Sin[42]],
{MakeBoxes[Sin[42],StandardForm],RowBox[{Sin,[,42,]}]},Null},Null},Null}


*)
```

so you can see that `With` literally replaces `x` by `Sin[42]` in the body and then evaluates it, while `Block` and `Module` do not.

Answer (score 15):

`With` allows definition of *local constants*. An example (that I recently posted as an answer) would have been a good candidate for this: a regular expresion.

```
With[{regex = RegularExpression[...]},
    If[... something with regex ...];
    If[... something else with regex ...]
]
```

Other uses would be if you need to precalculate a local constant (`Sin[20°]` etc) to save processing time when the value is needed more than once.

---

`Block` and `Module` seem like two things for the same purpose on first sight: scoping. However, the way they assign the variables is different: `Module` replaces only explicit appearances of variables, while `Block` also takes into account implicit ones.

Here's an example of that ([taken from the Mathematica documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/BlocksComparedWithModules.html)):

```
m = i^2
```

> ```
> i^2
> ```

```
Block[{i = a}, i + m]
```

> ```
> a + a^2
> ```

```
Module[{i = a}, i + m]
```

> ```
> a + i^2
> ```

---

*And why all this?*

The thing is again how Mathematica stores variables: `a=1` does not assign the value `1` to `a` - it creates a pattern defining that every time `a` appears in the code, it is to be *replaced* by `1`. In the sense of programming, this means that Mathematically dynamically changes its own code throughout the evaluation. The difference from this behavior to normal programming languages is why there's `Block` and `Module`. `Module` takes a snapshot of the code inside and starts evaluating it, replacing explicit occurences of the local variables; `Block` really *does* the replacement, and then starts going through the code. Memory hook: *B*lock comes before *M*odule in the alphabet, so it does the replacement first, and then starts evaluating.

Comment: I am not sure about "`Block` really does the replacement, and then starts going through the code", as for instance `Block[{x = a}, Hold[x]]` returns `Hold[x]`.

Comment: ... that is correct. Can we settle on a "for practical purposes"? :-)

Comment: But I think that for practical purposes this is really the distinction between `With` and `Block` ("this"=whether it's better to think of it as literal replacement or a scoping construct). But what do I know :)

Answer (score 14):

The difference is demonstrated by the following code snippet, where I've changed only the scoping construct. But let's first define a simple function:

```
f[x_]:=x+a
```

Now we first look at `Block`:

```
Block[{a=b}, Print[a]; a=3; f[x]+a]+foo[a,b]
(*
Prints: b
--> 6 + x + foo[a, b]
*)
```

As you see, the global value of a is temporarily assigned to b, then inside changed to 3. That is, not only the `a` inside the `Block`, but also the value of `a` in the function call from the `Block` is modified. Outside the block, the change is undone, including any change done inside the block (the `a=3`).

Let's now look at `Module`:

```
Module[{a=b}, Print[a]; a=3; f[x]+a]+foo[a,b]
(*
Prints: b
--> 3 + a + x + foo[a, b]
*)
```

As you see, this time the a in the function does *not* evaluate to b. Indeed, the `a` inside the `Module` is replaced by a temporary variable, as can be seen by not assigning a value:

```
 Module[{a},a]
 (*
 --> a$84
 *)
```

Finally, `With`:

```
With[{a=b}, Print[a]; a=3; f[x]+a]+foo[a,b]
(*
Prints: b
--> 3 + a + x + foo[a, 3]
*)
```

As you can see, the `a=3` now globally assigns 3 to `b`! That's because `With` actually replaces `a` with the "assigned" value, i.e. `b` in the whole body. That is, whereever the body contains `a` it's as if there was written `b` instead. But again, the value of `a` in the called function `f` is not affected.

From this, one can get the following guidelines:

In the general case, you want `Module` because its effect is most localized. You want `Block` is you explicitly want to temporarily change a global value, e.g. `Block[{$RecursionLimit=10000},RecursiveFunction[10000]]`. And `With` should be reserved for cases where you actually want a literal replacement.

Answer (score 8):

I think it is worth to point out another one peculiarity of `With` as compared to `Module` and `Block` which is little-known: `With` doesn't evaluate it's last argument at all, while both `Module` and `Block` evaluate their last arguments. In other words, the last argument of `With` will be evaluated only after leaving the `With` construct. This can be easily proven as follows:

```
With[{}, Stack[_]]
Module[{}, Stack[_]]
Block[{}, Stack[_]]
```

> ```
> {}
>
> Module[{}, Stack[_]]
>
> Block[{}, Stack[_]]
> ```

One can see that in the case of `With` the stack is empty because evaluation of `With` is already finished when `Stack[_]` is being evaluated, while in the case of `Module` and `Block` the `Stack[_]` is evaluated inside of the scoping construct.

---

Another thing which is useful to know is that all these constructs support **delayed assignments** for local variables:

```
With[{a := Random[]}, {a, a, a}]
Module[{a := Random[]}, {a, a, a}]
Block[{a := Random[]}, {a, a, a}]
```

> ```
> {0.637223, 0.284761, 0.180292}
>
> {0.139856, 0.55708, 0.585556}
>
> {0.888018, 0.961141, 0.451441}
> ```

Examples of use:

- [Put local variables for `Block` in a variable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24054/280)
- [Using `With[…]` with a list specification as a variable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/204119/280)

Comment: That lack of evaluation allows `With` to support tail recursion (and as far as i am aware, that's exactly the reason for it).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Just to be clear: by *tail recursion* you mean the sequental `With` (as `With[{a = 0}, {a = a + 1}, {a = a + 1}, a]`) or something else?

Comment: I mean something else; check "tail recursion" on stack exchange to get the actual definition (a bit long for a comment).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Actually I already [checked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33923/590388), but still do not understand how it is related to `With`. Can you provide an example?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau You've got me intrigued. Perhaps it is worth creating a separate question if the answer cannot fit in the comment?

Comment: I will try to come up with an example if and when time permits.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following example helpful for myself:

```
b = 3;
f[x_] := {b, x}
{Block[{b=6},f[2]], Module[{b=6},f[2]]}
```

gives `{{6,2},{3,2}}`

So basically the `b=6` in `Block` temporarily replaces the global `b=3`, including in already defined functions like `f`. Meanwhile, the `b=6` in `Module` doesn't really do anything since the `f[2]` doesn't directly refer to `b`; only the definition of `f` refers to the other (global) `b`.

From the documentation, `Block` is dynamic scoping while `Module` is Lexical scoping.

Comment: Isn't it covered in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/567/5478) or [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/569/5478)?